# How to integrate react native mini app into reactjs web app?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, web

I am currently working on migrating one of my projects from reactjs to react native web so that it can run on mobile and the web (I decided against using a PWA or web views like cordova since I want to learn react native). I was wondering what resources there are for combining a react mini app with a react web app so that I can transition slowly component by component to react native.

For example, the home page will all still be react until that is transitioned but first I might want to make the "About" page a react native mini app for web. I am looking for how to do this and eventually everything will be react native and therefore runnable on mobile.

Any resources would be great. I could only mainly find how to share code between the two and not how to combine the two.